# Dependency injection based on configuration?

Tags: c#, active-directory, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an app which uses `active directory` to retrieve users. Sometimes I need to work on the app but AD is not available. I use a wrapper class to retrieve the AD user. I would like to inject a different class based on the configuration. I was thinking on using an appSetting that would tell me the current configutarion and decide what type to use when injecting. Is it possible to get the current configuration without using a Web.config transform? Is it possible to inject objects using Unity based on Web.config transformations? Can you recommend a better approach?

[UPDATE]

I have a user repository class that loads the users from AD. All I need is to be able to change the implementation of this repository class so that when AD is unavailable I can load the users a different way. This would only be used for development, production would always access AD and retrieve users.

Comment: Yes indeed it is possible to configure Unity with configuration files or with code based on some configuration settings... But without information on you current usage of Unity it is very hard to suggest something more concrete.

Comment: I'm not getting what problem you have doing so... Just register 2 different implementation based on condition... `if (useFakeRepository) container.RegisterType(typeof (IAdRepository), typeof(FakeAdRepository)....`

Comment: My problem is how to calculate useFakeRepository? I can use a transform for Web.config but I need to figure out under which configuration the app is running. I would like to avoid having to add an appSettings.

Comment: I see - it was not exactly clear from the post that your problem have nothing to do with Unity, dependency injection, or repositories. Sorry for misunderstanding. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use preprocessor directives:

```
#if DEBUG
// register fake repository
#else
// register AD repository
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about preprocessors.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Dependency Injection is incredibly powerful, agile, and creates a separation of concerns.  The pitfall in your approach will come from validation.  You see, with this approach you have to choose a concrete implementation.

So how will you call those two classes?

```
public class LogToText : ILogger
{
     public void LogMessage(string message) { }
}

public class LogToEvent : ILogger
{
     public void LogMessage(string message) { }
}
```

You have these two implementations, but when you pass the interface to:

```
public class AD
{
     public AD(ILogger logger) { }
}
```

So the question will be do you feel that you can properly validate to choose the proper implementation effectively.  Otherwise, Dependency Injection may not work well. We don't entirely know the usage or goal, so our advice may not be truly beneficial.  Hopefully you see what I mean, because you'll have to see if you can't test a particular way.

Comment: I have a user repository class that loads the users from AD. All I need is to be able to change the implementation of this repository class so that when AD is unavailable I can load the users a different way. This would only be used for development, production would always access AD and retrieve users.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Abstraction for this:

```
public interface IPersonService
{
    IEnumerable<Person> Find(PersonSearchParameters searchParams);
    Person GetByAccountName(string accountName);
    [ETC...]
}
```

Then both your AD and Development implements this interface.

To make things easier, I suggest using StructureMap IoC, so you can easily do this:

```
x.For<IPersonService>.Use<ActiveDirectoryPersonService>(); //for production
```

or

```
x.For<IPersonService>.Use<MockPersonService>(); //for development
```

When using this you can, for instancce:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    IPersonService _service;

    public TestController(IPersonService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }
}
```

Instead of using an XML file for configuration in this case, I suggest using the Fluent code of Structure Map, it's better when refactoring and to avoid mistyping because it compiles.

StructureMap:
http://structuremap.net

Easy Installable via NuGET

Answer (score 0):

A different approach would be to use the build configuration, read back from the assembly.

```
var buildConfiguration = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyConfigurationAttribute>()?.Configuration;
if (buildConfiguration == "Debug")
{
    // register fake repository
}
else
{
    // register AD repository
}
```

Then it is safer to apply refactorings or automatic code clean up (e.g. ReSharper etc.). Depending on your current configuration, code cleanup can otherwise remove unused usings. What then leads to build issues if an other configuration is used.